# Twilio: loop through 5-6 numbers until somebody picks up

Tags: twilio

I am on a team that has to be on-call 24/7. Our team is comprised of 5-6 members and we each take a week.  If the business calls our dedicated on-call number (Twilio), I would like that to make an outbound call to a sequential list until somebody on that list answers the phone.

Is this possible using either C# or Python along with Twilio of course? I am not a developer, but if I can be pointed in the right direction I think I can figure it out.  It appears Twilio has voicemail detection so I'd imagine I would have to utilize that feature.

Answer (score 1):

Target has an Open-source project you can look at that may already meet your needs, powered by Twilio.

https://github.com/target/goalert

> GoAlert GoAlert provides on-call scheduling, automated escalations and
> notifications (like SMS or voice calls) to automatically engage the
> right person, the right way, and at the right time.

Comment: It appears PostgreSQL is a hard requirement, which might be a deal breaker as we are a MS shop.  However, this is exactly what we need... perhaps a bit overkill if anything.